# C - Change the position of the conditions in while loop leads to Segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I have a function to insert an element to a hash table like this in my program:

```
void insert(int key,int data)
{
    struct DataItem *newdata = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
    int  hashIndex;

    newdata->key = key;
    newdata->data = data;

    hashIndex = hashCode(key);

    while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL && hashArray[hashIndex]->key != -1)
    {
        ++hashIndex;
        hashIndex %= MAX_SIZE;
    }   

    hashArray[hashIndex] = newdata;
}
```

This works without any problem. However, when I change the position of the condition in while loop to this:

```
while(hashArray[hashIndex]->key != -1 && hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL )
```

There ís an "Segmentation Fault" error. And the program pointer stops at the while loop when I call the insert function.

I'm wondering what is the problem?

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL && hashArray[hashIndex]->key != -1)
```

It works because here, if first condition is false, the second one does not get executed — that is behavior of `&&` operator — so in case `hashArray[hashIndex]` is NULL, it does not access invalid memory by accessing `hashArray[hashIndex]->key`

Answer (score 1):

`C` has short circuit evaluation for boolean `&&`. This means that if the first expression evaluates to false, the second won't be evaluated and false will be returned directly.

Now in your case

```
while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL && hashArray[hashIndex]->key != -1)
```

if `hashArray[hashIndex]` turns out to be `NULL`, the second part won't be evaluated.

This means you are safe.

But what happens when you switch the order and `hashArray[hashIndex]` is indeed `NULL`? You dereference `NULL` before checking it and hence you get a Seg Fault.

So the best solution for you is to keep it as is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the first case you first check `hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL` and access `key` member *only* if the object exists. The second version will attempt to access the `key` member before making sure that object was created.

In other words, in the second version it may happen that `hashArray[hashIndex]` is `NULL` and so your first part of the condition (`hashArray[hashIndex]->key`) is equivalent to `NULL->key`, which leads to access violation.